# HTML alternative if plugin is not available

Tags: html, activexobject, browser-plugin

What is the best practice for displaying an HTML alternative when a browser plug-in is not available? I'm embedding the plugin with an object tag like so:

```
<object id="plugin0" type="application/x-myplugin"></object>
```

This is what an unknown plugin displays as in Google Chrome, however I'd like the solution to work on all browsers (i.e. FF plugin/Chrome plugin/IE ActiveX object)

[image: Image of "No plug-in available" error in Google Chrome]

-foot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about flash, whatever you place within the object tag will show up if flash is not supported.

Here's an example of a flash movie with a fallback image:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash data="yourmovie.swf" width="400" height="300">
<param name="movie" value="yourmovie.swf" />
<img src="noflash.gif" width="200" height="100" alt="" />
</object>
```

I typically test for plugins using javascript and write to the page based on the test results.

Comment: Thanks! Not flash actually, but the same idea :)