# alternative to html <div id="display_map"> when div is not available (google map goes in the div)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a google map showing on my webpage if I input an address using POST.
I am trying to have an alternative image show in its place before the address is typed. I have also tried just text but nothing shows.

```
......div id="display_map"  alt="Map goes here"></div>.............
```

I have already looked for an answer there:

[show alternate image when google street view is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286503/show-alternate-image-when-google-street-view-is-unavailable)

[HTML alternative if plugin is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065850/html-alternative-if-plugin-is-not-available)

[Show div when google map is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484486/show-div-when-google-map-is-used)

The `#display_map` comes from a javascript function

Code request:

```
<div id="display_map" style="width:300px;height:320px; " alt="Map goes here"></div> 


<div id="mapform">
<div class="map_values">
<label>Pin location will be </label>
<input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" value=""/>
<label>stored.</label>
<input type="hidden" id="lng" name="lng" value="" />
<label> Drag to tweak.</label>
<input type="hidden" id="zoom" name="zoom" value="" />
</div>
<form action="signin3.php" method="post">

    <p><b>Sign in OK:</b><input type="checkbox" name="signin" value="1" style="color: black; background-color: red" checked ><small><b> Required</small></b></p>

    <p><b>Note:</b>(optional)<br>
    <textarea name="note" id="note" rows="7" cols="30" maxlength="500" placeholder="Note your recent location or planned activity" style="color: black; background-color: lightgreen"></textarea></p>

<p>
    <span id="remaining">500 characters remaining</span>

</p>
<label>Address</label>
<input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="optional"/>
</br>
<label>city</label>
<input type="text" id="city" name="city" />
</br><label>state</label>
<input type="text" id="state" name="state" />
</br><label>country</label>
<input type="text" id="country" name="country" />
</br><label>zip</label>
<input type="text" id="zip" name="zip" />
</br>
    <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="Signin Ok + Save Note" />

</form>
</div>
<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['email'])){

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { // Handle the form.

                        $e= $_SESSION['email'];
            $signin= $_POST['signin'];                                 
            $note= $_POST['note'];

$add = urlencode($_POST['address']);
$city = urlencode($_POST['city']);
$state = urlencode($_POST['state']);
$country  = urlencode($_POST['country']);
//$zip = $_POST['zip'];

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$add.',+'.$city.',+'.$state.',+'.$country.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode); //Store values in variable
 // print_r($output);
if($output->status == 'OK'){ // Check if address is available or not
echo "<div class=\"display_map_details\">";
$xpert = $lat.','.$long;
$q = "UPDATE users2 SET message= '$xpert' WHERE id = 4 ";
$r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
//echo $xpert;
echo "</div>";
}

} // End of the main Submit conditional. 
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
function initialize() {

// Define the latitude and longitude positions
var latitude = parseFloat("<?php echo $lat; ?>"); // Latitude get from above variable
var longitude = parseFloat("<?php echo $long; ?>"); // Longitude from same
var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

// Set up options for the Google map
var myOptions = {
zoom: 13,
center: latlngPos,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
zoomControlOptions: true,
zoomControlOptions: {
style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE
}
};
// Define the map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("display_map"), myOptions);

// // Add the marker
// var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
// position: latlngPos,
// map: map,
// draggable: true,
// //icon:'pinkball.png',
// title: "<?php echo $loc; ?>"
// });


// var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  // content:"<?php echo $loc; ?>"
  // });
  addMarker(latlngPos, 'Default Marker', map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragstart', function(event) {
  //infowindow.open(map,marker);
      addMarker(event.latlngPos, 'Click Generated Marker', map);

       var lat, lng, address;

  });


}
  function addMarker(latlng,title,map) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: title,
            icon:'map-red.png',
            draggable:true,
             animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value= event.latLng.lng();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
        var coord = marker.getPosition();

//function get_id_val(coord);
//function get_id_val(coord){
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'map2.php',
    data: "&val=" + coord, 
    success: function(data) {
        //alert(coord);
        var ddd =99;
    }
} );
//}



        //alert(marker.getPosition());
        //alert(coord);
    });
       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
      document.getElementById('zoom').value =map.getZoom();
    });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});


</script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you have

Comment: A work-round was to read the json response from code: 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$myChosenLocation find values(lat,lng), and  of "formatted_address" and make them available to the javascript code under a new function : if (!isset($_POST['submitted'])) {  (is not submitted) The variables required: $lat, $long, $loc, I then copied the full javascript code into the same function under the variables and closed the script and then the function with <?php 
} and then continued into the if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) I now get a map set to a location at 1st page load.